# WPF binding from different sources

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol, multibinding

I'm projecting pretty simple, but effective UI for my app. The problem is that after some actions, lets say, refactoring, I came to re-project my design.

Previously I have had `ObsrvableCollection<UsbDevice>`. And my tab-control (with complicated custom style..) was binded to that collection. But now I need also something like 'Library' tab item to be there among with connected USB devices. Library IS NOT a collection, but just an business object, which holds some important XML data inside. Id like to use my tab control 'cause otherwise it will be necessary to invent some switching-logic: I can not let both USB device and Library to be selected at the same time.

So, my question is:
1) Maybe some of you, WPF GURUS, know the tricky way of binding from different source? the most obvious decision is to make something like `ObservableColelction<object>` somewhere else, but this is extremely ugly as for me.
2) Or, if that is impossible, maybe some of you has more easier solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can use [`CompositeCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx). In your `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl ...>
    <TabControl.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding UsbDevicesCollection}"/>
            <TabItem DataContext="{Binding LibraryViewModel}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </TabControl.ItemsSource>
</TabControl>
```

Of course you have to set proper names for your collection and library object.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a base class (BaseClass) that your UsbDevice and Library or
   any future class/object should inherit to.
2. Your collection should look like `ObservableColelction<BaseClass>`.
3. Finally, you need a DataTemplate for each of your concrete/derived classes; UsbDevice and Library.

Please take note that this will work perfectly provided that you are using an MVVM approach.

This will make your design more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending a generic collection like below:

```
public class CustomCollection<T> : List<T>
{

    public object Library { get; set; }

    .......//properties you need
    .......//properties you need

    public T CurrentTab { get; set; }

}
```

In this custom collection you can hold your collection and also can have your library object. like:

```
var UsbDevicesCollection = new CustomCollection<UsbDevice>();
UsbDevicesCollection.Add(new UsbDevice()); // add items as usual
UsbDevicesCollection.Library = new Object();//whatever kind of object is this
```

when you say "I can not let both USB device and Library to be selected at the same time." you can also write some sort of logic to do that in this class also.
and binding would be like:

```
<TabItem DataContext="{Binding UsbDevicesCollection.Library}"/>
```

hope this is what you are looking for.